# How to access Object's property itself while defining it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to dynamically use the previous property's value for calculation of next property.
I have a function like this in Typescript:

```
MacroGenerator(calories) {
  this.caloriedata['macroarray'] = [
    { 
      name: 'Low Carb, High Fat',
      pmacro: (Math.round(calories*220.46226218100)/100),
      pcals: (4*this.caloriedata['macroarray'][0].pmacro), // THIS IS HOW I TRIED ACCESSING THE PROPERTY AND GETTING ERROR
      fcals: (calories*0.3),
      fmacro: (Math.round(this.caloriedata['macroarray'][0].fcals/9)/100),
      ccals: (calories-this.caloriedata['macroarray'][0].pcals-this.caloriedata['macroarray'][0].fcals),
      cmacro: (Math.round(this.caloriedata['macroarray'][0].ccals/4)/100),
    }
  ]
}
```

I suppose the object isn't instantiated as of when I am trying to access.
Is there any way to access it?

Comment: Do you write the workout / nutrition app for yourself or is this going to be a commercial product? Do you plan to open source the code?

Comment: It is going to be a website for my upcoming Youtube channel :)
Code is open source on my git @ayush013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Javascript Getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

From MDN

> Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a
>   dynamically computed value, or you may want to reflect the status of
>   an internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method
>   calls. In JavaScript, this can be accomplished with the use of a
>   getter

```js
var obj = {
  a: 4,
  get b() {
    return this.a * 2;
  }
}

console.log(obj.b)
```

Comment: good call; a lot of devs, even good ones, forget about ES5...